# regex to match the minimum length of each word in a sentence in Python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to write a regular expression which checks the length of each word in a sentence and returns `True` if the length of all words are at least 3. Also, the whole sentence must be only in lowercase letters. For example, for the string "hello world" it must return true result and a false result for string "hi world".

The following regex does not work as intended, and it gives `True`.

> bool(re.compile('([a-z\s]{3,})+$').match("hi world")))

Comment: `^([a-z]{3,}\s?)+$`

Comment: You may use `re.match(r'\s*[a-z]{3,}(?:\s+[a-z]{3,})*\s*$', s)`

Comment: You don't need regex for that - split your sentence by whitespace and check if all of the words are at least 3 characters long: `if all(len(word)>2 for word in sentence.split())` ... Of course, you'll have a more difficult case if you have to account in punctuation, hyphened words etc. but even regex won't do it perfectly without post-processing.

Comment: @zwer Thanks for the comment. well... I could do that without regex, but I am most interested in the functionality of regex for such a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted this might not be a problem which requires regex, but the question could be a simplification of a bigger problem where using regex is the correct approach.

Instead of checking if every words meets your requirement my solution tries to find any word that doesn't meet your requirement. This means we are looking for:

1. Any character that is not a lowercase alphabetic or white-space character
2. Words smaller than the minimum length (3)

Resulting in the following regular expressions:

1. `[^a-z\s]`
2. `(^|\s)[a-z]{1,2}(\s|$)`

Combining these together gives: `([^a-z\s])|((^|\s)[a-z]{1,2}(\s|$))`. Which gives the following usable Python code:

```
import re
pattern = '([^a-z\s])|((^|\s)[a-z]{1,2}(\s|$))'

result1 = not bool(re.search(pattern, 'hello world'))
result2 = not bool(re.search(pattern, 'hi world'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need regex for this. You could do something like:

```
s = 'this is a sentence of some sort'
words = s.split()
test = [w for w in words if len(w) > 3]
print(len(test) == len(words)) # False
```

Or equivalently:

```
s = 'this is a sentence of some sort'
words = s.split()
acceptable = lambda x: len(x) > 3
print(len(words) == len(list(filter(acceptable, words))))
```

Or even:

```
s = 'this is a sentence of some sort'
words = s.split()
res = all(len(word) > 3 for word in words)
print(res)
```

Or, as @pault suggests:

```
s = 'this is a sentence of some sort'
all(len(w) > 3 and w.islower() for w in s.split())
```

Comment: + this is not a RegEx task

Comment: **1** The OP wants a regex solution. **2** There's a more efficient way to do that test in plain Python by using the `all` function, which short-circuits as soon as a particular word fails the test.

Comment: Or simply `all(len(w) => 3 and w.islower() for w in s.split())`

Answer (score 2):

You may try this too,

```
(?m)^(?=\s*([a-z]{3,}\s*)*$).*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/143)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to do this without regex:

```
def all_words_three_or_more(sentence):
  sentence_list = sentence.split(' ')
  for word in sentence_list:
    if len(word) < 3 or word.lower() != word:
      return False
  return True
```

Test Cases:

```
test_str_true = "this string will succeed"
test_str_false = "this string is false" 
test_str_false_caps = "FAIL THIS BECAUSE CAPS"

print(all_words_three_or_more(test_str_true)) # true
print(all_words_three_or_more(test_str_false)) # false
print(all_words_three_or_more(test_str_false_caps)) #false
```

Comment: You can use `word.islower()` rather than `word.lower() != word`

Answer (score 0):

Please try it:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('([a-z\s]{3,})+$')
all(pattern.match(x) for x in  "hello world".split())
```

output:

```
True
```

and

```
all(pattern.match(x) for x in  "hi world".split())
```

output:

```
False
```